Number of ions in positive corona discharge
In Positive Corona discharge, the positively charged ions move toward the negative electrode. If the positive electrode is a grid of thin wires, and the negative electrode is a flat panel, how do we calculate the charge of all the moving positive ions? Would it require just calculating the current of the discharge an dividing it by the velocity of the charged ions or is there another method/formula for this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
